# How to reduce pdf size with PDFLib with heavy images?

Tags: pdflib

I'm creating pdf with the help of the PDFLib engine. My requirement is quite heavy in terms of data which is going to be stored in pdf. One pdf will going to store around 300 Images. And will create around 100 pdfs at the same time. Mine images are been repeated so, I'll know which image will be places where. Now if I go with the image_load option of the PDFLib, the pdf size is around 100Mb. Is there any way so that I can reduce the size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `Templates`.

PDFlib supports a PDF feature with the technical name Form `XObjects`. However, since this term conflicts with interactive forms we refer to this feature as `templates`.

A PDFlib `template` can be thought of as an off-page buffer into which `text`, `vector`, and `image` operations are redirected (instead of acting on a regular page).

After the template is finished it can be used much like a raster image, and placed an arbitrary number of times on arbitrary pages. Like images, templates can be subjected to
geometrical transformations such as scaling or skewing.

When a template is used on multiple pages (or multiply on the same page), the actual PDF operators for constructing the template are only included once in the PDF file, thereby saving PDF output file size. Templates suggest themselves for elements which appear repeatedly on several pages, such as a constant background, or a company logo.

And will also reduces the size.